# mvc multiples routes for the same site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

here is my problem I have an existing web site

```
wwww.mysite.com
```

requirement ask me to allow users to use the same site like this

```
www.mysite.com
www.mysite.com/Home/Index
www.mysite.com/defaultsuborganisation/Home/Index
www.mysite.com/suborganisation1/Home/Index
www.mysite.com/suborganisation2/Home/Index
```

so I modify the routes configuration (RouteConfig.cs)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "OrganisationRoute",
  url: "{org}/{controller}/{action}/{data}",
  defaults:
  new
    {
    org= "defaultsuborganisation",
    controller = "Home",
    action = "Index",
    data = UrlParameter.Optional
  });
```

I work for all the expected routes except for `www.mysite.com/Home/Index`

Comment: You can use attribute routing for that!

Comment: Why would not you use multiple route registrations? I find it easier to read when separate registrations present for each unique group of routes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute routing like [Div](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4753489/div) said may be the better way to go, but you can add a fixed route ahead of your **OrganisationRoute** in the **RegisterRoutes()** method like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "DefaultHomeRoute",
 "Home/Index/{id}", 
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
 );
```

Comment: Yes, this is also a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing for this:

**Enabling Attribute Routing:**
To enable Attribute Routing, we need to call the MapMvcAttributeRoutes method of the route collection class during configuration in `RouteConfig`.

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

And on your action:

```
[Route("Home/Index")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return view();
}
```